# Android Tango HW access

Tags: google-project-tango

I am using Tango-enabled phone - Lenovo Tango Phab 2 Pro. I want to access all sensors available there and reading data in raw format.

Tango API is already providing "Motion Tracking", "Area Learning", "Depth Perception" but I am looking for a way how to access the raw sensor data instead of having those raw data already processed?

What is the way access sensors data directly?

Comment: The raw data for motion tracking is the wide angle camera feed and the raw data for the depth sensor is the point cloud, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Access camera frames uncorrected since I want to do "correction of wide angle optics - calibration" on my side.

Comment: Have you tried [Tango.OnFrameAvailableListener](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/reference/Tango.OnFrameAvailableListener)?

Answer (score 0):

For the visible light image sensors, you would use `TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable()`.  See:

- https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/group/camera

For depth, the best you can do is to capture a point cloud and use `TangoSupport_upsampleImageBilateral()` to interpolate the depth, for each pixel.

See:

- https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/group/depth
- https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/support/reference/group/depth-interpolation-support#group___depth_interpolation_support_1ga03a4e39d813814d837c24216f3ee105d

Note that if you're trying to pair a depth image with an image from the color camera, they will possibly be captured at different times.

Comment: is there a way to access it with No use of Tango API, i  do not want to use Tango API, just access HW features directly.

Comment: I have no idea about that.  You could try exploring the NDK, and see what it exposes.  https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___camera.html  However, you might need to find out details about your hardware platform, and additional files or documentation from the sensor manufacturers.  Be warned that Tango probably does a lot for us, including fusion of various depth methods, such as stereo and ToF.  Maybe you can get low-level ToF sensor access, but you'll probably have to do the stereo + fusion yourself.